# I am trying to change the text content of multiple buttons upon hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a script that will display a different text content when the mouse is hovered over a specific button.  I am building a portfolio website, and wish to have the title of the project, and when hovered display a description of the project before clicking.

I am able to change the content of a single button using JS by:

```
let newText = "New text goes here"

let btn = document.querySelector(".btn");

btn.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  this.textContent = newText;
})
btn.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    this.textContent = "Existing Text";
  })
```

I will obviously need more than one button to add my projects to the page, so I was looking for ways to simplify this.  I am currently trying to run something like:

```
const btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');

const DESCRIPTIONS = {
  "projectOne": "projectOne text goes here",
  "projectTwo": "projectTwo text goes here"
};

btn.addEventListener("mouseover", ({target}) => {
  this.innerText = DESCRIPTIONS[target.id];
  console.log(target);
})
```

But I'm getting the error: `Uncaught TypeError: btn.addEventListener` is not a function, although I can `console.log(btn)` and I can see the current array of buttons that I have created for projects.

I'm not sure if this is the perfect way to go about things, but all help would be greatly appreciated, as I'm scratching my head a little bit on this one.

I'm happy to supply any extra information that I've missed.

Thanks in advance,

Kaimac

Comment: As you rightly figured out, btn is an array, hence you need to do btn[0] or a better way would be to use document.querySelector(`.btn`). This would only return the first/only instance of the button

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I want to have the specific instance of the button change text, though.  ie: buttonOne is linked to projectOne, therefore when mouse hovers buttonOne, projectOne's doescription displays, if that makes sense.  I'll play around with the btn[] and see how I go though.  I'm working through the night at the moment so I might not get a chance to play around until tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely make it more modular if you have the button selectors and corresponding action encapsulated in an object/array. Think about a map of buttons vs descriptions. Then you can have a common function where you'd be using `document.querySelector('.buttonClassName')` to find the button and then add necessary callbacks to the click event.
This way, your js wouldn't have similar working code all over and would be cleaner.

Comment: At the moment when calling btn, I have an array of .btn that returns the number of buttons that I currently have active, which I'm thinking is a good start.

I currently have a DESCRIPTIONS function that holds key = projectID and it's desired text description.  I'm hoping to have the mouseover recognize which id I'm accessing, and display the corresponding text.

If I use .buttonClassName, will I have to run that same script for each button?  

I apologise if I'm being rookie here.  I start uni in a few months and I'm trying to learn as much as I can/get myself set up before I start.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array, so you need to loop over the elements:

```js
const btn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');

const DESCRIPTIONS = {
  "projectOne": "projectOne text goes here",
  "projectTwo": "projectTwo text goes here"
};

var i = 0,
  length = btn.length;
for (i; i < length; i++) {
  if (document.addEventListener) {
    btn[i].addEventListener("mouseover", ({
      target
    }) => {
      this.innerText = DESCRIPTIONS[target.id];
      console.log(target);
    })
  } else {
    btn[i].attachEvent("mouseover", ({
      target
    }) => {
      this.innerText = DESCRIPTIONS[target.id];
      console.log(target);
    })
  };
};
btn.addEventListener("mouseover", ({
  target
}) => {
  this.innerText = DESCRIPTIONS[target.id];
  console.log(target);
})
```